# calling controller from view using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to call controller and also pass the data that variable `mat` is holding. But it is not calling my controller function.Please help me, how to proceed?

```
$('#buttonadd').click(function () {
    var mat = $('#material_name').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: $("#baseUrl").text()+"gc_purchase/add_material_info"+mat,

        success: function (data) {
           $('#demo').html(data).show();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $('#material_name').text("Error encountered while saving the comments.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what u see on the console?

Comment: Please add `console.log($("#baseUrl").text()+"gc_purchase/add_material_info"+mat);` to your click eventhandler to check if the concatenate URL is correct.

Comment: Show the controller code.

Comment: would you please share your Action Method

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/AddBooking',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: { StartTime: StartTime, EndTime: EndTime, ProductId: ProductId },
            success: function (data) {
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my controller function..

public function add_material_info()
  {

```
$this->load->model('ma_model');
$data['query']=$this->ma_model->material_info();
```

}